# From where do anime streaming sites take their videos from?

Tags: streaming-sites

I was wondering - from where do anime sites find the anime they are streaming? I'd like to know how they get the content and from where.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Some from torrent sites or are ripping them from the disks or original streaming services.

Comment: ohh, so they download from there and display it then? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

*Legal* streaming sites like Crunchyroll, Viz, [and others](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/923/2516) get their source directly from the original distributor/publisher after [they get the license/rights to stream the series](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/feature/2012-06-11).

Outside of those sites (which are considered "gray area"), they use any possible sources, from ripping the video from the original streaming services and DVD/BD to downloading from existing sources, which is basically piracy since it's a copyright infringement to distribute works without permission, regardless if [they are already licensed or not yet licensed](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19024/2516).